# Jquery vs IE in dark alley - round 1 (slideup & slidedown)

Tags: jquery, slideup

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills. About to lose my mind solving the issue at hand but ultimately IE7 does not use jquery 'slideDown' and 'slideup' function as it should.

All other browsers work. My initial theory is the issue lying with the .focus (since ie does not recognize). When i switch the function to .click, it still does not function however.

Please save my life tonight.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $("#message").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({"height": "85px",}, "fast" );
        $("#button_block").slideDown("fast");
        return false;
    });

    $("#cancel").click(function() {
        $("#message").animate({"height": "30px",}, "fast" );
        $("#button_block").slideUp("fast");
    return false;
    });

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $("#message").animate({"height": "30px",}, "fast" );
        $("#button_block").slideUp("fast");
    return false;
    }); 

});

</script>
```

### HTML snippet requested

```
<div id="shout"></div>


<form method="post" action="shout.php">
   <textarea id="message" name="message" class="message" value="enter text here"></textarea>
                <div id="button_block" style="padding:0 0 15px;">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    <input type="submit" id="cancel" value="Cancel" />
                </div>
</form>
```

additionally, the 'shoutbox' created above this file does not work in ie7 either (although works just fine in any other browser). Code for it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    refresh_shoutbox();
    setInterval("refresh_shoutbox()", 15000);

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var name    = $("#name").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        var data            = 'name='+ name +'&message='+ message;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "shout.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(html){
                $("#shout").slideToggle(500, function(){
                    $(this).html(html).slideToggle(500);
                    $("#shout").val("");
                });
          }
        });    
        return false;
    });
});

function refresh_shoutbox() {
    var data = 'refresh=1';

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "shout.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(html){
                $("#shout").html(html);
            }
        });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Post an HTML snippet or make something on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: sorry works for me on the Mac. Here's the code for further testing. Hope it helps someone with IE7. http://jsfiddle.net/CUPrj/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to remember IE7 having issues with trailing commas on key value pairs. I would try removing the extra commas as see if it helps.

from:

```
$(this).animate({"height": "85px",}, "fast" );
```

to:

```
$(this).animate({"height": "85px"}, "fast" );
```

Comment: I am not around my office to actually test on ie7 but have tested on ie8 and it works fine (note: the code i originally had *also* worked on ie8 so could just be a 7 issue?)

Comment: It also works for me in IE8 but not IE7. I used this to test: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: good lord... now a second script doesn't function in IE7. I have added to notes if you get a chance to maybe run your eyes through it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the slideUp/slideDown as a callback from the animate method?

For example:

```
$("#message").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({"height": "85px",}, "fast", function() {
          $("#button_block").slideDown("fast");
        });        
        return false;
});
```

It's possible IE is having trouble because the height is not being taken up when the slideDown/Up is called.

Comment: @JM4 Along similar lines, make sure the element is "display:none;" before a slide-up (and the inverse as well)